# More than one search results page template for two searches on site

Tags: functions, templates, search, template-hierarchy

I have a site with two search fields, one on a page called 'blog' and one on a page called 'archive'. I am using `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` to call the forms. All of the sites posts are either put in the blog category or the archive category and I use those to organize everything. I have the searches working with this in my functions.php file, which is working perfectly to break up the two searches:

```
function archive_search_filter( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && 
wp_get_referer() == "http://localhost:8080/archive/" ) {
$query->set( 'category__not_in' , '9' ); 
    }
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && 
wp_get_referer() == "http://localhost:8080/blog/" ) {
$query->set( 'category__not_in' , '8' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'archive_search_filter' );
```

Both of the results pages for the searches go to search.php but I'm wondering if there is a way to send one to search.php and one to another template that I create depending on which category search it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. From the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect#Performing_a_redirect):

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    if( is_page( 'goodies' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/signup/' ) );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Looking at your code, I think you can figure out how to adjust this to your situation.